# Postgresql function returns composite - how do I access composite values as separate columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, composite

I have a Postgresql function which returns a composite type defined as (location TEXT, id INT). When I run "SELECT myfunc()", My output is a single column of type text, formatted as:

```
("locationdata", myid)
```

This is pretty awful. Is there a way to select my composite so that I get 2 columns back - a TEXT column, and an INT column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM myfunc()
```

You can [read more about the functionality in this article](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions).

Comment: Arghhhhhhhh. I can't believe it was that easy.

Answer (score 3):

Answer has already been accepted, but I thought I'd throw this in:

It may help to think about the type of the data and where those types fit into an overall query. SQL queries can return essentially three types:

- A single scalar value
- A list of values
- A table of values

(Of course, a list is just a one-column table, and a scalar is just a one-value list.)

When you look at the types, you see that an SQL SELECT query has the following template:

```
SELECT scalar(s)
FROM table
WHERE boolean-scalar
```

If your function or subquery is returning a table, it belongs in the FROM clause. If it returns a list, it could go in the FROM clause or it could be used with the IN operator as part of the WHERE clause. If it returns a scalar, it can go in the SELECT clause, the FROM clause, or in a boolean predicate in the WHERE clause.

That's an incomplete view of SELECT queries, but I've found it helps to figure out where my subqueries should go.